# Putting rows of ascending digits and eliminate rows of other digits, leaving other symbols intact

Tags: c

For example, sequence "aasdf123456785fg87" will be transformed into "aasdf12345678fg", using `getchar` and `putchar` and then using strings.

With `getchar` and `putchar`:

```
char c = 0, c_ = 0;
char flag = 0;
while ((c = getchar()) != '.')
{
    if (isdigit(c))
    {
        if (!isdigit(c_))
        {
            flag = 0;
            c_ = c;
            while (true)
            {
                c = getchar();
                if (!isdigit(c))
                {
                    if (flag)(putchar(c_));
                    putchar(c);
                    break;
                }

                if (c - c_ == 1)
                {
                    flag = 1;
                    putchar(c_);
                }
                c_ = c;
            }
        }
    }
    else putchar(c);

    c_ = c;
}
```

and using strings:

```
char str[100] = { 0 }, outstr[100] = { 0 };
int i = 1;
char flag = 0;
int c = 0;
gets(str);
while (true)
{
    if (isdigit(str[i]))
    {
        if (isdigit(str[i - 1]))
        {
            if (str[i] - str[i - 1] == 1)
            {
                outstr[c++] = str[i - 1];
                flag = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                if (flag)outstr[c++] = str[i - 1];
                flag = 0;
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (flag)
        {
            outstr[c++] = str[i - 1];
            flag = 0;
        }
        if (str[i] == '.')break;
        outstr[c++] = str[i];
    }
    i++;
}
puts(outstr);
```

This code is not great, and I ask you to make it easier to understand and more effective. The thing is that I need to show these programs to my teacher, and he's going to see them done as easier and smarter as possible. I just don't know if it's okay.

Comment: If you've covered that bit, you must remove this code to a function. Also I don't understand what you're doing with '.'. If the string contains period ('.') the loop terminates and `outstr` won't be properly terminated with a `'\0'`. Should that check not be for a `'\0'`?

Answer (score 1):

Review of the **getchar and putchar:** portion

1. Testing the "With getchar and putchar:" code would be easier if given a function declaration to see clearly what are inputs and outputs.  Example:

   ```
   void UpdigitsFilter_IO(void) {
   // or
   int UpdigitsFilter_IO(void) {
   ```
2. Code uses `'.'` as a terminator, but that is not listed as a design criteria.  Was this to be `'\0'`?
3. Code uses `char c`, whereas `getchar()` returns an `int`.  This causes issues in 2 places, when `EOF` is encountered and `char` outside the 0 - `SCHAR_MAX` (typically 127).  Proper use of `is...()` functions require values in the 0 to `UCHAR_MAX` range or `EOF`.

   ```
   // char c = 0;
   int c = 0;
   ```
4. Exiting the loop on `EOF` should occur  (2x  places)

   ```
   // while ((c = getchar()) != '.')
   while ((c = getchar()) != '.' || c == EOF)
   ```
5. There is a discrepancy between "ascending digits" and `if (c - c_ == 1)`.  The first implies "135" is acceptable as the digits are greater than previous, but code implies they need to be sequential.  Assume sequential.
6. The requirements are silent on single digits sequences.  Assume acceptable.
7. Check the return value of `putchar()`.  Maybe make this the function's return when non-zero.

   ```
   int retval = putchar(ch);
   if (retval) {
     return retval;
   }
   ```
8. Filtering will not stop if a `'.'` is encountered in the inner `c = getchar();`.  Add checks here for `'.'` and `EOF`.